# How to update successfully db field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
   string diagnostic = txtDiagnostic.Text;
   string SqlStr = "UPDATE ConsultasAnimais SET diagnostico='" + diagnostic + "' WHERE idConsultaAnimal =" + idConsulta + " AND idAnimal=" + GridView2.DataKeys[GridView2.SelectedIndex].Value + "";

    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlStr, lBD.SqlCnn);

    lBD.SqlCnn.Open();

    SqlDataReader Dados = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Dados.Close();
    lBD.SqlCnn.Close();
```

This code should be updating DIAGNOSTICO field on ConsultasAnimais Entity. No errors nor database data changes

Comment: Your code has SQLI vulnerability (assuming values in SQL come from a user or untrusted source).

Comment: Its an academic work, its not going to be implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExecuteNonQuery()` for **Insert**,**Update** and **Delete** Queries:

```
int NumofRowsEffected = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should make use of the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns
>   the number of rows affected.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: still not changing anything on the database

Comment: Can you make sure that you're updating a record that does exist? Maybe there is something wrong with your `where` clause.

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteReader` method of `SqlCommand` is for executing SELECT statements. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

And please, use parameterized queries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection